# Django crispy-forms / xadmin - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

Could someone help me understand what's going wrong here? I started a new Django project, logged into admin and created a "test" user. When I click on the user url, I could see all the editable fields (name, email, etc.) / user detail page.

Then I installed xadmin, ran migrations, etc.

All seems to work, except when I click on the user to see the detail page, it throws this error.

```
IndexError at /xadmin/auth/user/2/update/
list index out of range
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/xadmin/auth/user/2/update/
Django Version: 1.11.10
Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value:    
list index out of range
Exception Location: C:\Users\...\Documents\CSA\portal\portal\apps\xadmin\widgets.py in render, line 81
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.14
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\CSA\\portal\\portal\\apps',
 'C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\CSA\\portal',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xadmin-0.6.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.11.0-py2.7.egg',
 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\odf']

Error during template rendering
In template C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\templates\bootstrap3\field.html, error at line 28

list index out of range
18  
19          {% if field|is_checkboxselectmultiple %}
20              {% include 'bootstrap3/layout/checkboxselectmultiple.html' %}
21          {% endif %}
22  
23          {% if field|is_radioselect %}
24              {% include 'bootstrap3/layout/radioselect.html' %}
25          {% endif %}
26  
27          {% if not field|is_checkboxselectmultiple and not field|is_radioselect %}
28              {% if field|is_checkbox and form_show_labels %}
29                  <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="{% if field.field.required %} requiredField{% endif %}">
30                      {% crispy_field field %}
31                      {{ field.label|safe }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="asteriskField">*</span>{% endif %}
32                  </label>
33                  {% include 'bootstrap3/layout/help_text_and_errors.html' %}
34              {% else %}
35                  <div class="controls {{ field_class }}">
36                      {% crispy_field field %}
37                      {% include 'bootstrap3/layout/help_text_and_errors.html' %}
38                  </div>
```

Highlighting line 28.

I understand that "Index out of range" means Django is looking for something at Index x, but the index only goes to x-1, but I'm unsure why I'd be getting this when all I've done is install xadmin (and it's accompaying packages "crispy-forms" and "reversion".

**EDIT:**

The last item in the traceback was this:

```
C:\Users\...\Documents\CSA\portal\portal\apps\xadmin\widgets.py in render
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if DJANGO_11:
            input_html = [ht for ht in super(AdminSplitDateTime, self).render(name, value, attrs).split('\n') if ht != '']
            # return input_html
            return mark_safe('<div class="datetime clearfix"><div class="input-group date bootstrap-datepicker"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>%s'
                             '<span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">%s</button></span></div>'
                             '<div class="input-group time bootstrap-clockpicker"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o">'
                             '</i></span>%s<span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">%s</button></span></div></div>' % (input_html[0], _(u'Today'), input_html[1], _(u'Now'))) ...
        else:
            return super(AdminSplitDateTime, self).render(name, value, attrs)
    def format_output(self, rendered_widgets):
        return mark_safe(u'<div class="datetime clearfix">%s%s</div>' %
                         (rendered_widgets[0], rendered_widgets[1]))
```

With the error highlighting

```
'</i></span>%s<span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">%s</button></span></div></div>' % (input_html[0], _(u'Today'), input_html[1], _(u'Now')))
```

I've changed that to

```
(input_html[0], _(u'Today'), input_html[0], _(u'Now'))
```

and it works.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: How did you install xadmin? The latest version on pypi is from 2016 so it may not work with Django 1.11. You might have to install the repo from GitHub instead.

Comment: Do you mean xadmin? I downloaded the repo, put it in Project/my_app/apps (rather than run pip install). Reversion and crispy forms I installed with pip (well, pipenv).

Comment: Which repo did you download?

Comment: https://github.com/sshwsfc/xadmin

Comment: @Alasdair - edited my question, take a look. Managed to fix it, but not exactly sure why it works. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you might have hit [this issue](https://github.com/sshwsfc/xadmin/issues/505). Django 1.11 introduces [template-based widget rendering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.11/#template-based-widget-rendering) which may have required some changes to code. I'm not familiar enough with that part of Django or xadmin to comment on the code or your fix.